# Hide NavigationBar for one ViewController in Storyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, navbar

I have found many posts, but still no solution. I am trying to hide a NavigationBar on the initial `UIViewController`, but i want to still show it on the second `UIViewController`. Here is my storyboard:

[image]

When I turn off the Inferred Top Bar for my Main View Controller, it disappears in Storyboard, but it still shows when I run the app. When I do the same in to the NavigationBar in NavController, it disappears for all three (because they all inherit the no Nav Bar).

I want to show the NavBar in ScrollViewV View Controller, but have it hidden in `MainViewController`.

All Controllers have the corresponding .h or .m files, but I am confused on how to do this programmatically. Let me know if you need to see anything else. Thank you much!

Answer (score 43, accepted):

In your mainViewController, you can do following:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:animated];
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
```

---

You might want to show the Navigation bar when hiding this ViewController, for that do the following:

```
- (void)viewDidDisappear: (BOOL)animated
{
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:animated];
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternate answer!

Comment: This was the better answer to override the viewWillAppear. Thank you and sorry for not investigating further before answering.

Comment: @KyleClegg `viewDidLoad` method is only called for the first time when the ViewController is created.

Comment: This doesn't work when moving back from a view controller that has the nav bar hidden

Comment: @Sam Yes, the question was to only hide for one viewcontroller. If you want to go back to a viewcontroller where nav bar is hidden then remove the line `[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:animated];` so that the nav bar remains hidden

Comment: @user427969 sorry I mean going back from a controller with the nav bar hidden to a controller with it not hidden.

Comment: @Sam Are you sure you have implemented `viewDidDisappear` as mentioned in the answer? Another option you could try is implementing `viewWillAppear` in your parent viewcontroller and set `[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:animated];`

Comment: yup, just double checked. i think it's because another animation is ongoing (the pop)

Comment: doing it in `willDissappear` seems to work better, except when presenting a new VC modally (where you get a nasty flashing), so I've ended up with: `- (void)viewWillDisappear: (BOOL)animated
{

    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    if (!self.presentedViewController)
    {
        [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:animated];
    }
}`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep things in the Storyboard than edit the User Defined Attributes and 
set `navigationController.navigationBarHidden` as a Boolean checked.

Comment: This is a great suggestion

Comment: This works, but you will not be able to show the NavigationBar using the same trick in another ViewController. (User Defined Runtime Attributes are applied at Nib load time, not at viewWillAppear)

Answer (score 0):

```
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
```

Comment: Thanks! So that means since the others are inherited, I will have to set it to visible on the other ViewControllers I have correct? That was really easy.... Thanks again.

Comment: Also, when I hit back on the NavBar in my ScrollView View Controller, it shows the navigation bar again in Main View Controller... How do I make that permanent?

Comment: you mean you nead to remove the nav bar at all ? Thats not a very good idea, however if you still need it you need to extend the Nav Controller and in its `viewDidLoad` disable it the same way:
`self.navigationBarHidden = YES;`

Comment: Not completely. I want it to stay hidden at all times on my Main View Controller, but show up on the ScrollView View Controller and any others I may add.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you also need to add the following to the controller that you do want the navigation to appear.

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:animated];
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
```

Answer (score 0):

Anyone wanting to know how to do this in Swift?

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.hidden = true
}
```

Comment: From [doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621423-viewdidappear): "If you override this method, you must call super at some point in your implementation."